# React NavLink isn't opening in outlet when path is deeper than one level

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My Router on App.js is:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/selectedItem/:id" element={<PortfolioItem />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<Nav />}>
            <Route path="/Home" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="About" element={<About />} /> 
            <Route path="PortfolioList" element={<PortfolioList />} />
            <Route path="Contact" element={<Contact />} > 
            </Route>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This loads `<Nav/>` from Nav.js which contains the menu and NavLink paths as well as the outlet. But NavLinks on pages which are not in the same folder as Nav.js do not open in the outlet unless they point back to a page which is located at the same level as Nav.js

Is there a way to fix this without rewriting app.js and Nav.js, or is that not the issue?

Comment: Can you clarify what "But NavLinks on pages which are not in the same folder as Nav.js do not open in the outlet unless they point back to a page which is located at the same level as Nav.js" means exactly? Perhaps it would be easier for us to understand if you edited the post to include a complete [mcve] with all the relevant code you are working with and have an issue using.

Comment: Oh, yeah, you've got some weird stuff in your `Nav` component. It should only render one `Outlet` component for the nested routes it's wrapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out, I have `<Route path="/selectedItem/:id" element={<PortfolioItem />} />` in the wrong place. This works as expected:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          
          <Route path="/" element={<Nav />}>
            <Route path="/selectedItem/:id" element={<PortfolioItem />} />
            <Route path="/Home" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="About" element={<About />} /> 
            <Route path="PortfolioList" element={<PortfolioList />} />
            <Route path="Contact" element={<Contact />} > 
            </Route>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```